# Select string from a python dataframe containing column containing comma separated values python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a python Dataframe which looks like below

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Python (5), Hadoop (100), Hive (10), Hadoop Data (40) |
| 2 | SQL (30), Database (5), Hadoop (25) |
| 3 | SAS (60), Core Java (3), Kafka (9) |

I want to create a a dataframe which looks like below when i search for "Hadoop"

| ID | Value | Skill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Python (5), Hadoop (100), Hive (10), Hadoop Data (40) | Hadoop (100), Hadoop Data (40) |
| 2 | SQL (30), Database (5), Hadoop (25) | Hadoop (25) |
| 3 | SAS (60), Core Java (3), Kafka (9) |  |

I tried to convert the Value column into a list and then use code like
df['matching'] = [s for s in df['skill'] if "Hadoop" in s] but it does not seem to work

Comment: Is the value in your DataFrame one string or a list of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the value in your DataFrame is one huge string,  looking like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':['Python (5), Hadoop (100), Hadoop Data (40)',
                            'SQL (30), Database (5), Hadoop (25)',
                            'SAS (60), Core Java (3), Kafka(9)'
                           ]})

>>>
                                        Value
0  Python (5), Hadoop (100), Hadoop Data (40)
1         SQL (30), Database (5), Hadoop (25)
2           SAS (60), Core Java (3), Kafka(9)
```

this works for your purpose

```
df['Skill'] = df['Value'].str.findall('Hadoop \w*\s*\(\d+\)').str.join(', ')

>>>df
                                        Value                           Skill
0  Python (5), Hadoop (100), Hadoop Data (40)  Hadoop (100), Hadoop Data (40)
1         SQL (30), Database (5), Hadoop (25)                     Hadoop (25)
2           SAS (60), Core Java (3), Kafka(9)
```

adds a new column named `Skill` (also one string).

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks mosc9575, appreciate your response. I updated the sample data. The value in dataframe is one large string

Comment: @AshishMehta I updated the answer. Please post a real example in the first place next time. If you nee modifications on the `findall()` method you have to know that I am using regular experssions.

Comment: Thank you @mosc9575 for the solution, Appreciate it.. Am pretty new to Python and hence the miss.

Comment: If this is the solution to your question and helped you, please think about accapting it or voting it up.

Comment: yes it solves my question. I have accepted it. Looks like since this is my first query ever and i don't have enough reputation for my vote to be considered. Thanks for your help again